# How to alternate order in flowchart?

Tags: diagram, flowchart

**How to alternate order in flowchart?**

Imagine in the following flowchart,

[image]

"Want Fries" must be checked before checking "Want Drink". Now, I want to get an endpoint where, both of the conditions can be checked in any order. What should be the concise flowchart of it?

Update:

One possible diagram I made is the following but it looks not concise and also looks clumsy.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that this is possible?

Comment: I can make a valid one but that would be big. I want if there is any way to get a concise version.

Comment: Could you please attatch what you think you can do (i.e. the large version)?

Comment: @taylor.2317 please find the updated post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use ***fork*** and ***join*** symbols to represent parallel processing. It indicates the start or end of a section of processes that can be done independently. The UML notation for fork and join is a straight line.

See the below picture. [image: Flowchart]

Answer (score -1):

Please see the flowchart below:

[image: Flowchart]

Comment: In condition, "Drink first?" for both Yes and No you are ordering. Its wrong.

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: Its wrong. Please update it.

Comment: What is wrong with it?

Comment: After drink first there is no option for fries. Please try to verify possible paths before posting.

Comment: It asks if you want fries. If you don't, that means you want a drink (according to your flowchart).

Comment: Please read my comments carefully. If you choose drink first that does not mean you do not order fries after drink.

Comment: There is also an option to chose both!